# How to use a variable outside of its scope in node.js and nightmare.js (web scraping)

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

How to use a variable outside of its scope in node.js and nightmare.js (web scraping)

When i try to use the variable 'downloadLink' out of the await scope, it returns as undefined.

```
app.post('/search', function(req, res){
        const val = req.body.searchText;
        
        const nightmare = new Nightmare({ 
            show: true 
        });

        
        (async function() {

            const downloadLink = await nightmare
        
                .viewport(1200, 700)
                .goto('https://google.com/')
                .insert('#selector0')
                .click('#selector1')
                .click('#selector2')
                .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#selector3').href)
                .end()
            
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            console.log('download link ' + downloadLink) //this line prints a string
        
        })();

        console.log('download link ' + downloadLink) //this line returns undefined
    })
```

can i use 'downloadLink' outside of its scope and print it using the latter line of code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express supports async handlers, so you can refactor your method like this. No need to put the code under an async IIFE.

```
app.post('/search', async function(req, res){
    try {
        const val = req.body.searchText;
    
        const nightmare = new Nightmare({ 
            show: true 
        });
        
        const downloadLink = await nightmare
            .viewport(1200, 700)
            .goto('https://google.com/')
            .insert('#selector0')
            .click('#selector1')
            .click('#selector2')
            .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#selector3').href)
            .end()
        

        console.log('download link ' + downloadLink);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});
```